# Unable to sort object on groovy json

Tags: json, groovy

I'm trying to sort certain data (array of classes) based on certain field.
However data is not sorted correctly:

```
FCresJsonParse.sort { a,b -> b.residents.Name<=> a.residents.Name}
```

Sample JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "residents" : [
    {
       "linkedin" : null,
        "updated" : "2018-05-31",
       "twitter" : null,
       "organization" : null,
       "title" : null,
       "Name" : "Abc",
       "bio" : null,
    }, {
       "linkedin" : null,
        "updated" : "2018-05-31",
       "twitter" : null,
       "organization" : null,
       "title" : null,
       "Name" : "xyz",
       "bio" : null,
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the object you are calling `.sort {}` method on? I assume variable `FCresJsonParse` is the result returned from

```
new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonText)
```

or something similar. In such case `FCresJsonParse` is a `LazyMap` instance, so if you call `.sort {}` method on it like:

```
FCresJsonParse.sort { a,b -> b.residents.Name<=> a.residents.Name}
```

you wont get `FCresJsonParse.residents` array sorted as expected (in descending order). However, if you call:

```
FCresJsonParse.residents.sort { a,b -> b.Name<=> a.Name}
```

it will sort the array in descending order. In this case you can try sorting this array and assigning it back to the field, e.g.

```
FCresJsonParse.residents = FCresJsonParse.residents.sort { a,b -> b.Name<=> a.Name}
```

and then you will get `FCresJsonParse` similar to:

```
[residents:[[linkedin:null, updated:2018-05-31, twitter:null, organization:null, title:null, Name:xyz, bio:null], [linkedin:null, updated:2018-05-31, twitter:null, organization:null, title:null, Name:Abc, bio:null]]]
```